# How to selectively hide links in a promoted links webpart using JS

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, promoted-links

I have a promoted links webpart with three tiles where the links direct to various approval stages and I don't want the m all to show at once. I want to hide 2 of the tiles by default and reveal them when a list item displayed on the page using a dataview displays 'Awaiting Approval' in a choice field.

I think this should be possible with some javascript using the .show action but I'm not confident enough with JS to accomplish it myself.